# Example of two non-homeomorphic spaces with the same de Rham group

Tags: algebraic-topology, de-rham-cohomology

Can anyone give an example of two non-homeomorphic spaces with the same de Rham cohomology? I was thinking of $[0,1]$ and $\{0\}$ but does anyone have a more spectacular example?

Comment: Any compact manifold $M$ and the closed unit ball bundle in any positive-rank vector bundle over $M$ (which retracts onto $M$)...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang that's a bit advanced for me :D I don't know what a vector bundle is (i learned de rham cohomology without recourse to them)

Answer (score 1):

Your example generalizes to any space $X$ and $X \times [0, 1].$ Andrew Hwang's example is essentially the same.

Comment: What about two non-homotopic spaces that have the same de Rham groups?

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly more exciting example, try a torus with one puncture and a "pair of pants" (shown below). These are both manifolds (with boundary) which [deformation retract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)#Deformation_retract_and_strong_deformation_retract) to a figure 8.

[image: a punctured torus] $\quad\quad\quad$[image: a pair of pants]

A deep result ([de Rham's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#De_Rham%27s_theorem)) says that the de Rham cohomology of a manifold actually agrees with the singular cohomology (computed as a mere topological space)! Of course, the singular cohomology only depends on the homotopy type. In particular, we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
H_\text{de Rham}^n(\text{punctured torus}) 
&\cong H_\text{singular}^n(\text{punctured torus}) \\
&\cong H_\text{singular}^n(\text{figure 8}) \\
&\cong H_\text{singular}^n(\text{pair of pants}) \\
&\cong H_\text{de Rham}^n(\text{pair of pants})
\end{aligned}
$$

Lastly, we should check that a punctured torus is not homeomorphic to a pair of pants. But the punctured torus has only one boundary component (the puncture) while the pair of pants has three (the waist and two legs).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, unfortunately i only have 13 reputation and so i can't upvote it, but it's really appreciated